# CSS positioning help required

Tags: html, css

I want to make dropdown in list and I am making it with caret, the div looks like this

```
<div class="class-to-div1" id="{{ div.id }}" data-cardsnum="{{ div.num }}">
                    <div class="col-md-2 list">
                        <button onclick="text(this)" class="add-div btn btn-success btn-sm">add div</button>
                        <button class="delete-div btn btn-danger btn-sm">delete div</button>
                        <div class="class-to-div">
                            {% for innerdiv in div.innerdivs %}
                                <div class="list-item" data-column="{{ innerdiv.sveti_id }}" data-position="{{ innerdiv.position }}" id="{{ innerdiv.pk }}"> {{  innerdiv.text}} <span class="caret mycaret mydropdown"></span></div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want this `<span>` to be in right end of div with class `".list-item"`, but it's staying after `{{ innerdiv.text }}` whatever i do.

Comment: No idea how you want this to look. Could just `float: right;` [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cWh29/)

Comment: Please post the code you have tried as well.

Comment: can you provide any link or rendered html code?

Comment: @Ruddy float: right helped, Thx bro

Comment: @Nikgaru No problem, if you dont mind I would like to put this as an answer. That way other people may find it usefull.

Comment: @Ruddy of course I dont mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you could use `float: right;`. Heres a little bit about [floats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530755%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

### HTML:

```
<div>
    Testing Testing 
<span>Test</span>

</div>
```

### CSS:

```
div {
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
span {
    float: right;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cWh29/)